# can something besides the shebang set the interpreter?

Tags: shell-script, shebang, interpreter

I'm running a script (in tmuxinator) that tries to source another script (rvm). rvm explicitly does not allow sourcing from sh. I didn't think that would be a problem, because the shebang in the tmuxinator script is

```
#!/bin/bash
```

but when I insert the code suggested by the rvm people to source rvm from a script,

```
if [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
  source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
fi
```

-I get

```
sh: 6: [[: not found
```

Why is sh being used as the interpreter there? I've also used #!/usr/bin/zsh (which is the value of $SHELL in the interactive shell from which I called the script) and #!/usr/bin/env zsh, but they give the same complaint.

Comment: On the face of what you're saying, it should work, so you must have left something out. Post or link to the full script that you've added this snippet to, and tell us exactly how it's invoked.

Comment: I've actually pared the script down to just what I posted and get the same result. The script is being called by Ruby, with the Kernel#exec method, but I can't find any reason why that should be forcing the use of sh.

Comment: ...until I looked at the documentation for Kernel#exec. "The standard shell means always “/bin/sh” on Unix-like systems". Well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was the script was called from Ruby with

```
exec(script)
```

and exec always operates in the context of /bin/sh, the shebang line in the called script apparently notwithstanding.

Changing to

```
exec('/bin/bash', '-c', script)
```

works.

Answer (score 2):

Does RVM operate in a /bin/sh context?  This is likely the reason you're encountering this difficulty; the source'd script inherits the parent's interpreter.  See: http://ss64.com/bash/source.html

> . (source or dot operator)
>
> Read and execute commands from the filename argument in the **current shell context**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I'm not reaching the source command, though. I hit the double bracket operator and sh complains about it because it's a bashism.

Comment: What's the value of `ls -ld /bin/bash` ?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 959168 Sep 19 2012 /bin/bash` though as I said below the real problem was Ruby's exec command forcing the use of /bin/sh unless explicitly told to do otherwise. Thanks for the reminder about this question; I forgot to mark the solution I found as answered.